# Convert Objective-C code to Swift: delegate

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm now learning a function which is written in Objective-C. But I don't know Objective-C language. When I'm converting the code to Swift, I got stuck at the delegate functions.

The code in .h file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SCPopViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)viewHeight:(CGFloat)height;
- (void)itemPressedWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end

@interface SCPopView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak)     id      <SCPopViewDelegate>delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSArray *itemNames;

@end
```

and I'm trying to convert the code as:

```
protocol popViewDelegate: class {
    func itemPressedWithIndex(index: Int)
    func viewHeight(height: CGFloat)
}
```

but for the three last sentences, i don’t know how to deal with them, especially the one with `id` and `delegate`.

Can I get any help, please? I will do more effort to learn Swift. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4.2

Converted Code for Swift 4.2

```
protocol SCPopViewDelegate: class {
    func viewHeight(_ height: CGFloat)
    func itemPressed(with index: Int)
}

extension SCPopViewDelegate {
    func viewHeight(_ height: CGFloat) {}
    func itemPressed(with index: Int) {}
}

class SCPopView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: SCPopViewDelegate?
    var itemNames: [Any] = []
}
```

This code is based on code converted by an online code conversion tool, the link to the [original](http://swiftify.me/nru0d4) generated code.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the protocol ends with the first @end statement.

The @interface after that is the definition of an Objective-C class, SCPopView.

You don't need to care about the latter part if you're just trying to define the protocol in Swift.

FYI:

```
@interface someClass: NSObject
```

is equivalent to

```
class someClass: NSObject
```

In Swift.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol SCPopViewDelegate{
    optional func viewHeight(height: Float)
    optional func itemPressedWithIndex(index : Int)
}

class DGViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate:SCPopViewDelegate! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate?.viewHeight?(Float(self.view.frame.size.height))
    }
```

And in the class that implements the delegate

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    var vc = DGViewController()
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    vc.view.backgroundColor = (UIColor.redColor())
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true) { () -> Void in}
}

func viewHeight(height: Float) {
    println(height)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. This helps me a lot on understanding the codes. I will try soon. If there's still any problem, I hope I could still get a little more help from you. Thank you! @Dare